# Finding the solutions of $xp^2-2py+4x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discriminant

I am trying to find the general solution, $p$ and $c$ discriminant and hence the singular solutions (if any) of the following D.E. where $p=\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$. $$xp^2-2py+4x=0$$

The obvious thing to do is isolate $p$ using the quadratic formula. The $p$-discriminant is $4y^2-16x^2$ so I suspect one or both of $y=\pm 2x$ could be the envelope of the general solution (i.e., singular soln. of our D.E.).
$$p=\frac{y}{x}\pm \sqrt{\left(\frac yx\right)^2-4}$$

Substitute $y=tx$ to get:
$$x\cdot\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}=\pm\sqrt{t^2-4}$$
Integrating:
$$\ln|cx|=\pm \ln\left|t+\sqrt{t^2-4}\right|$$
where $c$ is the parameter of the general soln.
Now we have two cases:

1. $$cx=t+\sqrt{t^2-4}\\ \implies cx^2=y+\sqrt{y^2-4x^2}$$
2. $$cx=\frac{1}{t+\sqrt{t^2-4}}=\frac{t-\sqrt{t^2-4}}4\\ \implies cx^2=y-\sqrt{y^2-4x^2}\\ \text{where } 4c\mapsto c$$

I am unable to decide which one to go with for finding the $c$-discriminant. Is there any other way to solve this D.E. instead of isolating $p$ by quadratic formula?

**Update**: I realized I had made a lot of silly mistakes. I've fixed them. Now it's clear that collectively, the two cases yield (take $c/2\mapsto c$):
$$c=\frac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2-4x^2}}{2x^2}\\ =\frac{-(-y)\pm\sqrt{(-y)^2-4x^2\cdot 1}}{2x^2}$$
Using the quadratic formula (in reverse), the $c$-discriminant turns out to be $y^2-4x^2$. This confirms that $y=\pm 2x$ are indeed envelops and hence, singular solutions.
$$\phi(x,y,c)=x^2c^2-yc+1=0$$
See [this Desmos slideshow](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fa9cb6pagy) (graph of the envelope and the family $\phi$).

**Alternate approach:**
Isolate $y$ in the original D.E.
$$y=\frac{px}{2}+\frac{2x}{p}$$
This seems a little off from the Clairut's form i.e., $y=px+f(p)$. Substitute $u=x^2$. Denote $\mathrm dy/\mathrm du$ by $m$. So differentiating w.r.t. $y$, we have $\frac{1}{m}=\frac{2x}p$ i.e., $p=2mx$.
$$y=um+\frac{1}{m}$$
This is in Clairut's form i.e., $y=um+f(m)$ so the general soln. is given by $y=uc+f(c)$ i.e., $$y=uc+\frac{1}{c}=cx^2+\frac{1}{c}$$ And the singular soln. can be determined by eliminating $m$ from the D.E. using $u+f'(m)=0$ i.e.,  $m=\pm1/\sqrt u$. $$y=\pm 2\sqrt u=\pm 2x$$

Answer (score 2):

Try polynomials of degree $2$ to get the general solution $$ y = c x^2 + \frac{1}{c}$$
and singular solutions $y = \pm 2 x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "try" a polynomial?

Comment: I mean substitute a polynomial for $y$ in the differential equation and see what the coefficients need to be in order to get the equation to be true.

Comment: Oh, I see! It works, I substituted $y=ax^2+bx+c$, $p=2ax+b$ which yields $b=0$ and $ac=1$ (which checks with the soln. in my post update). But how did you know that the soln. would be a polynomial and that too one of degree $2$?

Comment: If you're going to try something, polynomials are often a good choice.  If $y$ has degree $d$, the first two terms would have degrees $2d-1$ but only cancel for $d=2$.